# windows phone 8 longlistselector loop through all childs

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, code-behind, longlistselector

In my app, i have a longlistselector and i set the "DataContext = list" in the event PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded. Inside this longlistselector, i have this code:

---

```XAML
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Margin="5,10" >
        <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
            <Grid Margin="10,8" Tap="Grid_Tap_1" x:Name="gridPasta" Tag="{Binding Id_pasta}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Nm_pasta}" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontSize="24"/>
                <Border Background="#E3F4FF" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="100">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Qtde_pasta}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to set the background color of the specific Grid after i fill the LLS. I have search on internet about access LLS childs, but, nothing works. i have tried this link ([Loop through longlistselector to get checkbox in itemtemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695101/loop-through-longlistselector-to-get-checkbox-in-itemtemplate)), but the "SearchElement" not find the specific Grid.

My question is, how can i access this specific Grid after i fill the LLS?

Note: The specific Grid is known comparing the "Id_pasta" of the Grid.

Thanks for help.

Comment: If all you want to do is highlight, you can do it two ways.  Using a VisualState Storyboard, or binding.  I have a simple example here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070203/wp8-highlight-selecteditem-longlistselector/25101536#25101536

Comment: Hi friend, after i posted the question, i found this link (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Highlight-a-selected-item-30ced444) and i did like that! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could add simple bool property (and implement PropertyChanged) to the class you're using for this datatemplate, bind it as background to the grid and use converter to convert it to desired backgroundcolor if true or false.